# Cant install vs 2013 express

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Express in my new computer about 1 month ago. Yesterday when I started the VS, I have got a response that in order to continue using VS, I have to sign in my Microsoft account. I did so **but** from that point, I can't launch VS. Every time I do so, the VS stops running after one second and I must close it by the task manager. I have uninstalled  and installed again several times, but it doesn't help. Who can help me successfully installing VS 2013 express ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to try.

FIRST, make sure all your Windows Updates are in.  I've seen that block installs.

SECOND: Also type in 'remove products', sort by date, and see what goodies are at the top of the date list in 'removed products'.  Might be something lingering.

THIRD: Try installing VS2013 community edition and see what happens...  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx .  Its more powerful than express anyway.